# Safe Area don't appear when switching programmatically UITabBarController Swift iOS

Tags: swift

When I'm trying to switch UITabBarController programmatically with code:

```
self.selectedViewController = self.viewControllers?[2]
```

before user switching tabs through tab bar, the result is shown in image below.

[image: views overlapping safe area zones]

but after switching through tab bar:

[image: views placed as planned]

I'v tried to use `view.layoutIfNeeded()` but it doesn't help. How I can force instantiate safe area?

Comment: read this it might help https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/positioning_content_relative_to_the_safe_area?changes=_1

Comment: all views are positioned correctly and all constraints relates to safe area, but when switching programmatically UIKit ignores safe area. On second screenshot showed how views places when switching through tab bar by tapping on cart item